# How to obtain the derivative of Rodrigues vector and perform update in nonlinear least square?

Tags: slam

I am now interested in the bundle adjustment in SLAM, where the Rodrigues vectors $R$ of dimension 3  are used as part of variables. Assume, without loss of generality, we use Gauss-Newton method to solve it, then in each step we need to solve the following linear least square problem:
$$J(x_k)\Delta x = -F(x_k),$$
where $J$ is the Jacobi of $F$.

Here I am wondering how to calculate the derivative $\frac{\partial F}{\partial R}$. Is it just like the ordinary Jacobi in mathematic analysis? I have this wondering because when I look for papers, I find many other concepts like exponential map, quaternions, Lie group and Lie algebra. So I suspect if there is any misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but is too long for a comment.

I think you need to give more information about how the Rodrigues vector appears in your F.

First off, is the vector assumed to be of unit length.? If so that presents some difficulties as now it doesn't have 3 independent components. If you know that the vector will lie in some region (eg that it's z component will always be positive), you can work round this.

If instead the vector is normalised before use, then while you could then compute the derivatives, the resulting Jacobian will be singular.

Another approach is to use the length of the vector as the angle through which you rotate. However this means you need a special case to get a rotation through 0, and the resulting function is not differentiable at 0. Of course if this can never occur, you may be ok.